# How to set visibility and attr in jquery 3

Tags: visibility, attr, jquery-3

After upgrading JQuery 1 to JQuery 3 in our application, some JQuery code stopped working.

I tried looking at https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ but could not get help

Previous Code

```
$("#top_data_label").css("visibility", "visible");

$("#"+element).attr("class", "disable-link").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

What changes I need to make in the above code to make it working as per JQuery 3 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#top_data_label").css("visibility", "visible");

    $("#"+element).addClass("disable-link");
    $("#"+element).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Do not forget to put the js in on document ready because it will not work if you don't.

(See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw72nLqa/) which include a document ready)

Comment: $("#top_data_label").css("visibility", "visible"); does not work in JQuery 3. Are you providing solution as per JQuery 3?

Comment: I edited my answer, indeed you should put your jquery in a dom ready